# Sylius ShopApiPlugin Can't add products to cart

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'am trying to add a product to my cart using the ShopApiPlugin made for Sylius.
When I try to add a product thru `/carts/mytokenoid/items` with the json body 

`{
    "productCode": "iphone9",
    "quantity": 5
}`

I get this response

```
{
"tokenValue": "mytokenoid",
"channel": "US_WEB",
"currency": "EUR",
"locale": "en_US",
"checkoutState": "cart",
"items": [
    {
        "quantity": 5,
        "total": 4800,
        "product": {
            "code": "iphone9",
            "name": "iPhone 9",
            "slug": "iphone-9",
            "averageRating": 0,
            "taxons": {
                "others": []
            },
            "variants": [
                {
                    "code": "iphone9",
                    "axis": [],
                    "nameAxis": [],
                    "price": {
                        "current": 2000,
                        "currency": "EUR"
                    },
                    "images": []
                }
            ],
            "attributes": [],
            "associations": [],
            "images": []
        }
    }
],
"totals": {
    "total": 6896,
    "items": 4800,
    "taxes": 0,
    "shipping": 2096,
    "promotion": -5200
}, (...)
```

But when I do `/shop-api/carts/mytokenoid` to check my cart content, it is empty, nothing was added. Also I checked the database and the cart is there with the correct token but no items.
Does anyone know how can I solve this? I already tried with authorization token and without. Got the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
You just have to uncomment the "- tactician.middleware.doctrine" line in the `config/packages/league_tactician.yaml`